# scaling stores duplicate data on db in Flask

Tags: python, flask, apscheduler

I am using Flask-APScheduler on my program and it works correctly but when I scale my app it stores duplicate data on database. How can I resolve this problem? I am new in Python.

```
scheduler = APScheduler()
scheduler.init_app(app)

@scheduler.task('cron', id='store-users', hour='*')
def store():
  # store user in database

scheduler.start()
```

I am using docker-compose for scaling:

```
docker-compose up --build -d --scale app=2
```

If I add app=10 it stores 10 unique users on users table

Comment: Hmmm, this would be easier with `gunicorn`

Comment: Do you have any examples? @roganjosh

Comment: I'm desperately digging but I think that part of the launch script is back at my old company :/ Basically, you need to do something like "preload" or "prefork" in gunicorn to make sure that you only get the master process running `apscheduler` and not each worker process.

Comment: That said, it doesn't do anything about the fact you have multiple docker containers. If that's through kubernetes or something then my approach won't work because the containers are separated